# Convert process.stdin numeric file descriptor to a FileHandle?

Tags: node.js

How can I convert the numeric file descriptor in `process.stdin` to a `FileHandle` object like those returned by `fs.promises.open()`?

Rationale:

- **want** to work with stdin or a named input file in a uniform way
- **hate** that uniform way to be based on numeric file descriptors (which *could* be done by using `filehandle.fd`, but eughh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be a stable way to get a `FileHandle` from a `fd` value, at least as of 19.2.0. There is a complicated work-around here that might work, but it is clearly not a recommended approach: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43821

If you're okay not supporting Windows, you could do:

```
import fs from "node:fs/promises"

const inputFileHandle = await fs.open("/dev/stdin", "r")
const outputFileHandle = await fs.open("/dev/stdout", "w")
```

It doesn't actually use the same underlying file descriptor as `process.stdin.fd` and `process.stdout.fd` (0 and 1, respectively), but it should achieve basically the same effect.